# Converting Flat CSV into hierarchical JSON using java jackson API

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson

I have CSV defined as below.

```
    employee.name,employee.age,employee.dept.name,employee.dept.id,employee.dept.address.firstLine,employee.dept.address.postCode
    John Doe, 28, Sales,1001,21st Street,WX2 2XV
    Sam Smith, 22, IT,2001,22nd Street,XX2 2VV
```

I would like convert the above CSV into following JSON structure

```
    [
        "employee":{
            "name":"John Doe",
            "age":28
        },
        "dept":{
            "name":"Sales",
            "id":1001,
            "address":{
                "firstLine":21ndStreet,
                "postCode":WX22XV
            }
        }
        "employee":{
            "name":"Sam Smith",
            "age":22
        },
        "dept":{
            "name":"IT",
            "id":2001,
            "address":{
                "firstLine":22stStreet,
                "postCode":XX22VV
            }
        }
    ]
```

So that my Jackson ObjectMapper use the JSON and converts that into following Employee Object.

```
    class Employee {
        String name;
        int age;
        Dept dept;
    }


    class Dept {
        String name;
        int id;
        Address address;
    }


    class Address {
        String firstLine;
        String postCode;
    }
```

I have used CSVMapper to load the CSV file but could not find straight forward way to convert into an ObjectMapper so that I can build the underlying Java Objects.

Assumption is that CSV Header contains the actual attribute and object names.

Please accept my thanks in advance.

I do not want to use annotations and I need to convert this CSV into legacy java objects.

Comment: I cannot help you with JSON but please check your example for typos. Your Jackson   Object Mapper Address firstline, and JSON employee not empoloyee.

Comment: The JSON looks kind of odd to me .. Don't you want to have JSON Array instead of single json object holding the employee, department data?